# Why do some methods end with a number in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Why do some methods end with a number in ffmpeg such as avcodec_alloc_context3()

I google it and look over the ffmpeg development conversion, but can't find the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are newer versions, usually with more flags or variables as input.

Let's the original was `av_somefunc(struct * a, char * b)`. Then a new revision is added. It will be `av_somefunc2(struct * a, char * b, int c)` with the definiton of the earlier function changed to something like

```
{
    return av_somefunc2(a, b, 0)
}
```

where the fixed value of the new inputs preserves the existing behaviour of `av_somefunc()`.

However, you should use or switch over to the latest iteration when you can.